# Adding mirror reflection on the picture frame that can see the content inside and the reflection of the environment

Tags: mirror, reflection

[image]

i want to add a reflection mirror on the black frame that can see the content in the pink plane and the reflection of the environment. is there any way . thank you

Comment: Are you using Eevee or Cycles?

Answer (score 0):

**EEVEE**

1. Create a plane
2. Set primary shader to Diffuse BSDF
3. Plug Diffuse BSDF into a shader to RGB node and route that node to a ColorRamp
4. Plug the ColorRamp’s alpha into a Principled BSDF shader’s alpha, and then that into a Material Output surface
5. Go to Render settings, Film section, and check transparent
6. In the plane’s Material tab, ensure Blend Mode is set to “Alpha Blend”
7. Make sure that you are in Rendered View (it does not work in Material Preview) and your Reflection Plane is placed slightly above the mirror surface. You can increase the Distance parameter inside Reflection Plane just to be sure that it covers everything.

**Cycles**

For the mirror material:

1. Set metallic to 1
2. Set roughness to 0